# How to make svn follow a symbolic link to a file in a different project?

Tags: svn, versioning, svn-externals

I have two repositories A and B with LaTeX files/projects. Repository A contains
a bibliography file mybib.bib and I would like to use this file in
repository/project B as well. I created a symbolic link in repository B to
mybib.bib but if my colleague checks out B, the file is not found. How can I
teach svn to follow the symbolic link (the file mybib.bib in repository A)? As
far as I could figure out, one could use SVN externals, but the commands I tried
failed so far, e.g. `svn propset svn:externals '/path/to/mybib.bib
https://host/of/repos/A' .`  leads to `svn: E195005: Invalid svn:externals
property on '/path/to/repos/B': target '/path/to/mybib.bib' is an absolute path
or involves '..'`

Also, does a solution (if it exists) work if the file mybib.bib would not be under version control in some repository already or would this require a totally different approach?

Related topics are (... but neither addresses the problem for non-experienced
'SVN external users'): 
[SVN external file workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134566/svn-external-file-workaround) 
[Can we set a single file as external in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355956/can-we-set-a-single-file-as-external-in-subversion) 
[How do I properly remove an svn:externals and replace it with a local (non-external) copy of the same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044649/how-do-i-properly-remove-an-svnexternals-and-replace-it-with-a-local-non-exter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "non-experienced 'SVN users'" must read SVN Book before (or better - instead) asking questions
2. You can't use file-externals with cross-repository definition: only files in the same repository can be used
3. [Second answer in first linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134729/960558) contain clear answer on your question
4. Reading [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) will help you to write correct svn:externals definition: now it's inversed in REMOTE|LOCALPATH